# How can I replace a word that was clicked

Tags: javascript

Let's imagine they wrote "hello world my friends" and if I chick on the word "my" the text should be `"hello world <span> my </span> friends"`

then if I click on the word "world" it would be: `"hello <span> world </span> my friends"`

How can I replace a word that was clicked by wrapping that same word in a span and then putting it in the previously typed text?

**my code works correctly the first time, but then it doesn't work**
just in case the content of the div is dynamic, it is for a chat

```js
function play() {
  const test = document.getElementById('test')

  let text = test.innerText || test.textContent;
  console.log(text)
  if (!text) {
    return false
  }
  const s = window.getSelection();
  var range = s.getRangeAt(0);
  var node = s.anchorNode;
  let init = 0

  if (text.length > 0 && window.getSelection) {
    while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') != 0) {
      range.setStart(node, (range.startOffset - 1));
      init = range.startOffset - 1
    }
    range.setStart(node, range.startOffset + 1);

    do {
      range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset + 1);

    } while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') == -1 && range.toString().trim() != '');

    var str = range.toString().trim();

    let first = text.substring(0, init + 2)
    first = `${first} <span>${str}</span> ${text.substring(init + 2 + str.length, text.length)}`
    console.log("changed",first)
    test.innerHTML = first
  }
}
```

```css
#test {
  border: 4px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable onclick="play();" id='test'></div>
```

Comment: **How can I replace a word that was clicked by wrapping that same word in a span and then putting it in the previously typed text?** - Can you elaborate via example ?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example:**

```js
function play() {
  const test = document.getElementById('test');
  const text = test.innerText || test.textContent;
  
  if(!text) return false;
  
  const select = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  const index = select.startOffset;
  
  const focusNode = select.startContainer;
  if(focusNode.parentNode.nodeName == "SPAN") return false;
  const nodes = focusNode.parentNode.childNodes;
  
  let result = '';
  
  nodes.forEach(node => {
    const nodeText = node.innerText || node.textContent;
    
    if(node == focusNode) {
      const words = nodeText
                    .split(' ')
                    .reduce((accu, cur, idx, arr) => {
                      const len = cur.length;
                      accu['pre'] += idx ? arr[idx-1].length : 0;
                      const preLen = accu['pre'];

                      accu['arr'].push([
                        preLen + idx,
                        len + preLen + idx
                      ]);
                      return accu;
                    }, {'pre': 0, 'arr': []});

      const word = words['arr'].find(e => index >= e[0] && index <= e[1]);

      result += `${nodeText.slice(0, word[0])}<span>${nodeText.slice(word[0], word[1])}</span>${nodeText.slice(word[1])}`;
    }
    else {
      result += nodeText;
    }
  });
  
  test.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```css
#test {
  border: 4px dotted blue;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable onclick="play();" id='test'></div>
```